# StackedColumn chart shows weird column width

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

It's really a simple task I am doing here. I need to put two series as StackedColumn and 1 Point series together in one ChartArea. Below is the code. 
Each series only has three DataPoints for test purpose.

The resulting chart looks in the first picture below. The width of the stacked column looks slim. If I change the data of the Point series to 1 point per month over the three months, the resulting stacked column width looks just fine (picture 2). Also, if I use Column instead of StackedColumn for s1 and s2, the column width will be all good (Picture 3), no matter what data in the Point series s3.

Can anybody explain what's going on here and how to fix the problem in picture 1.

```
        Series s1 = new Series("s1");            
        s1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
        //s1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
        s1.XValueType = ChartValueType.Date;
        s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint((new DateTime(2016, 1, 1)).ToOADate(), 100));
        s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint((new DateTime(2016, 2, 1)).ToOADate(), 100));
        s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint((new DateTime(2016, 3, 1)).ToOADate(), 100));

        Series s2 = new Series("s2");
        s2.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
        //s2.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
        s2.XValueType = ChartValueType.Date;
        s2.Points.Add(new DataPoint((new DateTime(2016, 1, 1)).ToOADate(), 200));
        s2.Points.Add(new DataPoint((new DateTime(2016, 2, 1)).ToOADate(), 200));
        s2.Points.Add(new DataPoint((new DateTime(2016, 3, 1)).ToOADate(), 200));

        Series s3 = new Series("s3");
        s3.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;
        s3.XValueType = ChartValueType.Date;
        s3.Points.Add(new DataPoint((new DateTime(2016, 1, 1)).ToOADate(), 400));
        s3.Points.Add(new DataPoint((new DateTime(2016, 1, 4)).ToOADate(), 400));
        s3.Points.Add(new DataPoint((new DateTime(2016, 1, 7)).ToOADate(), 400));
        //s3.Points.Add(new DataPoint((new DateTime(2016, 1, 1)).ToOADate(), 400));
        //s3.Points.Add(new DataPoint((new DateTime(2016, 2, 4)).ToOADate(), 400));
        //s3.Points.Add(new DataPoint((new DateTime(2016, 3, 7)).ToOADate(), 400));

        cht.Series.Add(s1); cht.Series.Add(s2); cht.Series.Add(s3);

        cht.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Months;
        cht.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
        cht.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        cht.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
```

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

[image: Picture 3]

Comment: I found a walk around myself: put the stackedcolumns and point series in separate but overlapping/transparent ChartAreas. Althought I know there is some special dealing in the background for stackedColumn charts. I hope someone can shed some lights on that. Can you hear me, TaW? :)

Comment: Yes, I'm here :-)  - Did you see my answer?

Comment: @uqji Users who have not commented under your post will not be notified if you mention them. If for any reason you want to notify someone who has not commented below your question, you should post a comment under one of their posts.

Comment: Or add the @ before their name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [MSDN on StackedColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489221.aspx):

> Stacked series must be aligned. Otherwise, data points will be
>   rendered incorrectly. For more information, see [Aligning
>   Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456707.aspx).

Here is says:

> Two Series are considered to be aligned if they have the same number
>   of data points and the same data in their corresponding X values.

Since the `Point` and the `StackedColumn` series' are not aligned, the columns make room for the missing columns.

This can't really be avoided if you want more points to show than stacked columns because :

> Number of series : One or more (multiple series are stacked).

You could try to **overlay** a **second** `ChartArea` with the first one and then add a Point series. See [here for two examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+overlay+ChartArea)! It may take some test to find the right way to set up the second chartarea and its axes..

Comment: Thanks @TaW for you great comments. I am going down that route with overlaying ChartAreas. I admit stackedColumn is something special that deserves some special treatment.